# Can not find generator - after ember cli install

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After installing ember-cli, i've noticed that I can't generate anything.

for instance:

```
Could not find generator 'devise:install'. Maybe you meant 'ember:install' or 'ember:route' or 'generator'
Run `rails generate --help` for more options.
```

Any ideas why this is happening?  I have `gem 'devise' in gemfile and have bundled.

I also had activeadmin gem, but the generator wasn't being recognized either.

here are the available generators:

```
Rails:
  assets
  controller
  generator
  helper
  integration_test
  jbuilder
  job
  mailer
  migration
  model
  resource
  scaffold
  scaffold_controller
  serializer
  task

Coffee:
  coffee:assets

Ember:
  ember:adapter
  ember:bootstrap
  ember:component
  ember:controller
  ember:install
  ember:model
  ember:resource
  ember:route
  ember:template
  ember:view

Ember-cli:
  ember-cli:init

Erb:
  erb:controller
  erb:mailer
  erb:scaffold

Haml:
  haml:application_layout

Js:
  js:assets

TestUnit:
  test_unit:generator
  test_unit:job
  test_unit:plugin
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I reset my computer and it worked.

I read somewhere running, `spring stop` may have worked as well...I am not 100% sure I was running it, but I may have been.  Resetting stopped it.

Comment: I had the same problem and stopped spring and it worked form me